# How does Rust implement reflection?

Tags: reflection, rust

Rust has the `Any` trait, but it also has a "do not pay for what you do not use" policy. How does Rust implement reflection?

My guess is that Rust uses lazy tagging. Every type is initially unassigned, but later if an instance of the type is passed to a function expecting an `Any` trait, the type is assigned a `TypeId`.

Or maybe Rust puts a `TypeId` on every type that its instance is possibly passed to that function? I guess the former would be expensive.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

First of all, Rust doesn't have reflection; reflection implies you can get details about a type at runtime, like the fields, methods, interfaces it implements, *etc.*  You *can not* do this with Rust.  The closest you can get is explicitly implementing (or deriving) a trait that provides this information.

Each type gets a `TypeId` assigned to it at compile time.  Because having globally ordered IDs is *hard*, the ID is an integer derived from a combination of the type's definition, and assorted metadata about the crate in which it's contained.  To put it another way: they're not assigned in any sort of order, they're just *hashes* of the various bits of information that go into defining the type. [1]

If you look at the [source for the `Any` trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/any.rs.html), you'll see the single implementation for `Any`:

```rust
impl<T: 'static + ?Sized > Any for T {
    fn get_type_id(&self) -> TypeId { TypeId::of::<T>() }
}
```

(The bounds can be *informally* reduced to "all types that aren't borrowed from something else".)

You can also find the definition of `TypeId`:

```
pub struct TypeId {
    t: u64,
}

impl TypeId {
    pub const fn of<T: ?Sized + 'static>() -> TypeId {
        TypeId {
            t: unsafe { intrinsics::type_id::<T>() },
        }
    }
}
```

`intrinsics::type_id` is an internal function recognised by the compiler that, given a type, returns its internal type ID.  This call just gets replaced at compile time with the literal integer type ID; there's no *actual* call here. [2]  That's how `TypeId` knows what a type's ID is.  `TypeId`, then, is just a wrapper around this `u64` to hide the implementation details from users.  If you find it conceptually simpler, you can just think of a type's `TypeId` as being a constant 64-bit integer that the compiler just *knows* at compile time.

`Any` forwards to this from `get_type_id`, meaning that `get_type_id` is *really* just binding the trait method to the appropriate `TypeId::of` method.  It's just there to ensure that if you have an `Any`, you can find out the original type's `TypeId`.

Now, `Any` is implemented for *most* types, but this doesn't mean that all those types *actually have* an `Any` implementation floating around in memory.  What actually happens is that the compiler only generates the actual code for a type's `Any` implementation if *someone* writes code that requires it. [3]  In other words, if you never use the `Any` implementation for a given type, the compiler will never generate it.

This is how Rust fulfills "do not pay for what do you not use": if you never pass a given type as `&Any` or `Box<Any>`, then the associated code is never generated and never takes up any space in your compiled binary.

---

[1]: Frustratingly, this means that a type's `TypeId` can *change value* depending on precisely *how* the library gets compiled, to the point that compiling it as a dependency (as opposed to as a standalone build) causes `TypeId`s to change.

[2]: Insofar as I am aware.  I *could* be wrong about this, but I'd be *really* surprised if that's the case.

[3]: This is *generally* true of generics in Rust.

Comment: Interestingly, [the documentation for std::any](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/) uses the phrase "runtime reflection", though it seems likely that what they're referring to is not what most of us mean by "runtime reflection" since this only enables type checking and type casting rather than inspecting the contents of an arbitrary struct.

Comment: OK.  By reflection,  I mean RTTI.

Comment: You can use `TypeId` without `Any` for limited forms of ad-hoc per type special casing, without runtime cost.

Comment: I would argue that the "runtime" part is bogus

Comment: So Rust is pretty much like C++ in this case... like `dynamic_cast` just RTTI

Comment: @Konrad: No.  Rust doesn't have any RTTI, C++ does (assuming you don't disable it).  Rust has no equivalent to `dynamic_cast`, because it doesn't have the necessary RTTI.

Comment: @DK oh right. I just read that it has typeid assigned at compile time.So it's pretty much like `typeid` in C++ but wait C++ has any too https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any