# How to match on data type in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to match on the datatype of a generic field of a struct and react accordingly. My general idea was like this (code doesn't compile):

```
struct Foo<T> {
    bar: T,
}

fn main() {
    let x = Foo::<String> {
        bar: "world".to_string(),
    };

    match x.bar {
        String => println!("It's a string!"),
        u32 => println!("It's a u32!"),
        _ => println!("Something else"),
    };

    println!("end of program!");
}
```

The error message from the compiler:

```
warning: unreachable pattern
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
11 |         String => println!("It's a string!"),
   |         ------ matches any value
12 |         u32 => println!("It's a u32!"),
   |         ^^^ unreachable pattern
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unreachable_patterns)]` on by default

warning: unreachable pattern
  --> src/main.rs:13:9
   |
11 |         String => println!("It's a string!"),
   |         ------ matches any value
12 |         u32 => println!("It's a u32!"),
13 |         _ => println!("Something else"),
   |         ^ unreachable pattern

warning: unused variable: `String`
  --> src/main.rs:11:9
   |
11 |         String => println!("It's a string!"),
   |         ^^^^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_String`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

warning: unused variable: `u32`
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
12 |         u32 => println!("It's a u32!"),
   |         ^^^ help: consider prefixing with an underscore: `_u32`

warning: variable `String` should have a snake case name
  --> src/main.rs:11:9
   |
11 |         String => println!("It's a string!"),
   |         ^^^^^^ help: convert the identifier to snake case: `string`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(non_snake_case)]` on by default
```

What I wanted was for `x` to match the first one. I'm actually not sure what I want to do can be done, but what would achieve the desired effect?

Comment: The short answer is "not right off the bat". You might find this question useful: [How does Rust implement reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36416773/1233251)

Comment: Rust uses `CamelCase` for structs, enums, and traits. You should be using `Foo`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Idiomatic Solution**

Create a trait which constrains the parameter `T` in `Foo`, implement any specific behavior as an associated function of this trait.

Example:

```
trait PrintMe {
    fn print_me(&self);
}

impl PrintMe for String {
    fn print_me(&self) { println!("I am a string"); }
}

struct Foo<T: PrintMe> {
    bar: T
}

fn main() {
    // ...
    x.bar.print_me();
}
```

This is *principled* generic programming, where you declare exactly the difference of behavior of the possible generic parameters, so that there is no surprise.

See also:

- [Why is this match pattern unreachable when using non-literal patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28225958/155423)

---

**Exact Solution**

Rust can indeed query types: each type has a unique [`TypeId`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/struct.TypeId.html) associated, and you can match on `TypeId` with a series of `if` checks. It's clunky.

```
fn print_me<T>(x: &Foo<T>) {
    if TypeId::of::<T>() == TypeId::of::<String>() {
        println!("I am a string");
    } else // ...
}
```

But please... don't do that :)

Comment: Thank you, Matthieu. That clears things up. I think I need to change my design in general, I keep laying out my code "C style". Thanks!

Comment: +1 for "don't do that", and I'll just point out that Rust *has* `enum`, which is a better (shorter, clearer, idiomatic and compile-time checked) way of writing all those `TypeId::of` checks.

Comment: @trentcl: It depends. `enum` is for closed-polymorphism whereas `trait` is for open-polymorphism... if that makes sense.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It makes sense. You'd already mentioned traits, though, so I thought I'd point out the other solution

Comment: What's bad about using TypeId for cases where enums can't be used (open world) and traits also don't cut it?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: the function signature doesn't document that `TypeId`, this means switching to a different (optimized for your usecase) string type will compile, but have a different behavior. Worst, no matter you do, you can't have both your optimized string _and_ the behavior of string, so you can throw away the code (if not yours) as it's become useless to you.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm not sure I understand. The use case I'm thinking about is a match that accepts any value (as "message") and just checks if a message is of a certain type, and if it is, then casts it to the concrete type and reads the playload.
I think it would be exactly the use case for "Exact Solution" in your answer. I don't see how else this could be achieved.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: There are uses for `TypeId` -- it wouldn't exist otherwise -- and yours may be one. MAY. There's a _cost_ though. The compiler won't diagnose passing a type that the function doesn't handle -- which it would both in the enum or trait solution. Hence, from a static typing point of view, `TypeId` is always a bit of a hack/technical debt, and re-architecting the application to avoid it may be beneficial. MAY, again.

Comment: @MatthieuM. thanks for the update. In my case I don't need such checks. If a function in the pipeline is interested in a message, it should be able to receive it. If a message is not processed at all, it's fine as well.

Answer (score 3):

### A more general look at matching over types

Basically, you hardly can match on the type, instead you have to use rust's **traits**.

Here is a helpful introduction for Rust's traits: 
https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait.html

I will explain simply how to match over type so it's okay if you don't know how to use traits.

Here is how to more generally change behavior depending on the type:

1. Define a trait that is going to do something depending on the type.
2. Add a function that takes in what you need to do something with it.
   It will take the variable with a type that varies as `self`. Don't add a body to that function, just follow the definition with a semicolon `;`.

   ```
   trait DoSomething {
       fn someFunction(&self);
   }
   ```
3. Implement the trait for all the types you wanted to match for: `String` and `u32`.
   This is the part where you can code different behavior for each type.

   ```
   impl DoSomething for String {
       fn someFunction(&self) {
           println!("It is a string!")
       }
   }
   impl DoSomething for u32 {
       fn someFunction(&self) {
           println!("It is a u32!")
       }
   }
   ```
4. Instead of matching on an element, call the method in the trait on it.

   ```
   struct Foo<T> {
       bar: T,
   }

   fn main() {
       let x = Foo::<String> {
           bar: "world".to_string(),
       };

       // the call of the method someFunction will differentiate the type of x.bar
       x.bar.someFunction();
   }
   ```

TLDR: in Rust, to match over type, we create a trait, implement a function for each type and call it on the element to match.