# Function comparing 2 variables of any type

Tags: rust

A tricky problem. I have to implement a function `fn eq( a, b )` comparing a and b. The function should return `false` if either types of variables are different or variables have different values. The function should return `true` if both type and value are the same.

A possible solution is to use `dyn Any` as Netwave advised. But such a solution has limited application because it restricts arguments of `eq` with `static` constraint. Maybe it is possible to come up with a more practical implementation? Playground of such a [solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=daba5ec7ea227bad4e18d8e38d6e51ef).

Comment: Is this homework? What is a realistic scenario where you have two variables of different types, but need a comparison function to tell you so?

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41596628/how-to-match-on-data-type-in-rust

Comment: Hello Herohtar. No it's not homework. Purpose is self-education. Realistic application in the system of evaluation logical expressions. No it's not duplicate, its very good question. Question you refer does not answer my question. Why stackoverflow is so often such negative?

Comment: I was just wondering if it was homework because it didn't sound like a problem one might encounter in a typical scenario, and homework questions are required to be identified as such. Did you read the answer to the other question? At the very bottom it shows a way to compare the types of two variables. Once you do that, comparing the values should be obvious.

Comment: I question why you would want comparing `Logic<A, B>` and `Logic<C, D>` to even be defined. I feel like you're opening yourself up to runtime errors that should be compiler errors.

Comment: @kos, please do not edit answered questions to update with more requirements. Keep them simple and in case something else bubble up you can open another related question. I thin you are overcomplicating things: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c291d9a19db991d8c5c554312a6a7473

Comment: @kmdreko it should give true only if both type is the same and value is the same. imagine comparing 2 logical expressions.

Comment: @Netwave but opening a new question for a bit more restricted version also not an option, right? how to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, playing with [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html) is not so difficult to implement something:

```rust
use std::any::Any;
use std::any::TypeId;

fn eq<T: Any + Eq, Q: Any + Eq>(a: T, b: Q) -> bool {
    if TypeId::of::<T>() == TypeId::of::<Q>() {
        let b_as_t = &b as &dyn Any;
        // safe to unwrap, we matched the type already
        &a == b_as_t.downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap()
    } else {
        false    
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert!(!eq("foo", 1));
    assert!(eq(1, 1));
    assert!(eq(&1, &1));
    assert!(!eq(&'a', &1));

}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c038acb82ddf4aaf590b3606c89ab8b7)

As per the comments, it may be possible to have another version that works over references directly:

```rust
use std::any::Any;
use std::any::TypeId;

fn eq<T: Any + Eq, Q: Any + Eq>(a: &T, b: &Q) -> bool {
    if TypeId::of::<T>() == TypeId::of::<Q>() {
        let b_as_t = b as &dyn Any;
        // safe to unwrap, we matched the type already
        *a == *b_as_t.downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap()
    } else {
        false    
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert!(!eq(&"foo", &1));
    assert!(eq(&1, &1));
    assert!(eq(&1, &1));
    assert!(!eq(&'a', &1));
    let s1 = "foo".to_owned();
    let s2 = "foo".to_owned();
    assert!(eq(&s1, &s2));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=15056fd85910cb9b4d4da32713c10867)

Comment: Thank you Netwave, that works, but it has limited application because it restricts arguments of `eq` with `static` constraint. Maybe it is possible to come up with a more practical implementation? I have the problem demonstrated in the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7a57cdf10086dcb09adf8a0f79c28e20

Comment: @Kos, maybe you are overcomplicating things? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c291d9a19db991d8c5c554312a6a7473

Comment: I would say I am investigating what Rust can and cant. Such information shared might be useful for other adopters of Rust.

Comment: Unfortunately the `'static` requirement is more insidious than it appears at first. Let's say you want to compare two values that allocate, such as `Strings`. You'd like to compare them by reference, i.e. not to have `eq` consume the allocations just in order to compare them. But doing [the obvious](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1b0505780d373da4db9a1816c50daca5) doesn't compile because references aren't static.

Comment: @user4815162342 indeed. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Netwave A quick fix that makes it slightly better would be to accept references to begin with, [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=db9310986525e0b59789d9f544b2754f). It would still require the referred-to types to be `'static`, but at least you could compare values of such types (which include strings etc) without consuming them.

Comment: @user4815162342 yeah, I actually updated the answer with that just with you previous message hint. Thanks olr the tips!

Comment: Thanks, this makes the answer much more useful for non-`Copy` types. It's a real shame one can't use `TypeId::of` on non-static types.