# How can I get all implementations of a struct and call it?

Tags: rust

This is my dummy code that doesn't actually work, I would like to know how, or is there a way to achieve this functionality.

Currently if I want to do this, I need to define an enum and match, which is inefficient and difficult to maintain.

```rust
pub fn mainrun() {
    let aimpl = MyStruct {
        Name: "bar".to_string(),
    };
    // dummy method collector
    let some_dummy = impl_method_collector(&aimpl);
    for k in some_dummy {
        k();
    }
    /*expected to get 
    bar say one
    bar say two
    bar say three
    */
}

struct MyStruct {
    Name: String,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn one_fn(&self) {
        println!("{:?} say one", self.Name)
    }
    fn two_fn(&self) {
        println!("{:?} say two", self.Name)
    }
    fn three_fn(&self) {
        println!("{:?} say three", self.Name)
    }
}
```

Here is how I achieve the same in Go. I want to achieve something like this with Rust.

```golang
package main

import "reflect"

func main() {
    println("start")
    astr := &MyStruct{"bar"}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(astr)
    vNums := v.NumMethod()
    for i := 0; i < vNums; i++ {
        v.Method(i).Call([]reflect.Value{})
    }
    /*expected to get 
        start
        bar say one
        bar say three
        bar say tow
    */
}

type MyStruct struct {
    Name string
}

func (m *MyStruct) FnOne() {
    println(m.Name, "say one")
}

func (m *MyStruct) FnTow() {
    println(m.Name, "say tow")
}

func (m *MyStruct) FnThree() {
    println(m.Name, "say three")
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to call every method belonging to a type? May I ask: *why?*

Comment: As far as I know Rust doesn't have SFINAE, and without it it's not clear for me how can compiler be sure that every instance method doesn't require some other argument. Without it the program might get ill-formed easily

Comment: How do you plan to handle methods with different argument lists and return types?

Comment: @gspr Yes, I want to simplify the routing design so that each implementation is automatically registered instead of enumerating the matches, finding them is just the first step

Comment: @thebusybee This is a little complicated. When writing golang, it will use middleware to encode and decode, serialize and deserialize, and the ultimate goal is to automatically register with the routing table, instead of having to modify the enumeration table every time a new function is added, and develop new The function only needs to focus on what structure is received and what structure is returned, which reduces development pressure and is quite smooth

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36416773 Rust does not have that form of run-time reflection. It is more idiomatic to make all intervening structs implement a common trait.

Comment: On a side note, [struct field names are generally in lower_snake_case](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html#casing-conforms-to-rfc-430-c-case).

Comment: @E_net4ismydisplayname It means that it is possible to make the struct return all its implementations through the trait? How can I make a function like this?

Comment: It means that it is more idiomatic to depend on a trait of your design than on runtime reflection. How this trait is written is up to what exactly you wish to achieve. Should compile time reflection be a possibility, the implementation may be assisted with macros.

Comment: Does [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d99a43fb09bb538d26edd057adb4dfbb) do what you want?

Comment: @Jmb Yes, this is it! Thank you so much, I'm almost desperate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar using a macro that defines all the "route" methods along with any "global" methods that want to use the list of "routes":

```
macro_rules! make_routes {
    ($name:ident $(fn $method:ident (&$self:ident) { $($code:tt)* })*) => {
        impl $name {
            $(fn $method (&$self) { $($code)* })*
            
            // Here you define the method (or methods) that operate on the list
            // of "routes".
            fn call_all (&self) {
                $(self.$method();)*
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    a: i32,
}

make_routes!{
    MyStruct
    fn route1 (&self) {
        println!("Route 1");
    }
    fn route2 (&self) {
        println!("Route 2 (a = {})", self.a);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d99a43fb09bb538d26edd057adb4dfbb)

Note that if the methods you want to call take extra parameters, then you will need to list the parameter names for each method (but you don't need to list the types since they must be the same anyway):

```
macro_rules! make_routes {
    ($name:ident $(fn $method:ident (&$self:ident, $param:pat) { $($code:tt)* })*) => {
        impl $name {
            $(fn $method (&$self, $param: i32) { $($code)* })*
            
            fn call_all (&self, param: i32) {
                $(self.$method (param);)*
            }
        }
    }
}

make_routes!{
    MyStruct
    fn route1 (&self, param) {
        println!("Route 1 (param = {})", param);
    }
    fn route2 (&self, param) {
        println!("Route 2 (a = {}, param = {})", self.a, param);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1de26dec4a7c926ca64c674a7c7bbe77)

For more details on macros, you can read [The Little Book of Rust Macros](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/).